# I got float RGB values, but PIL method 'putpixel' doesn't accept float type numbers

Tags: python

I am using putpixel method from PIL module.
It seems that it expects that r,g,b values are integers.
I am trying to draw a mandelbrot set and the formula I'm using to calculate color returns float type numbers. 
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Answer (score 1):

If your values are already scaled to 0-255, try:

```
im.putpixel((x, y), tuple(int(c) for c in pixel))
```

If they're scaled 0-1, you just need to add a multiply:

```
im.putpixel((x, y), tuple(int(c*255.999 for c in pixel))
```

P.S. the preferred way of doing pixel level access is with the `load` function:

```
pix = im.load()
pix[x, y] = tuple(...)
```